# How can I make a Back button on a Tabbed View App in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode

I have already multiple views that are in the tab bar at the bottom. In one of those view controllers (home view), I made a button connecting to another page (feed view) that isn't in the tab bar.

How can I make a back button from the feed view to the home view?

I've searched and I've only found tutorials for single view apps.

Reminder: the feed view isn't in the tab bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a Navbar then connect the left button(Back Button) to the view controller and do `self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` inside of that button action event

or

Just link a button from the view and do

`self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`

The way to go from tab view to a separate view use this code inside of the button action to go to a non TabBar view

```
let objSecondVc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as? ViewController
objSecondVc!.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
present(objSecondVc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Then in the seperate View Controller to go back to the TabBar View use

`self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`

Comment: correct if you follow the the code blocks, it will take you to a view Controller if you give it the identifier and call it as shown in the 3 block section. Then use the dismiss to get back

Answer (score 0):

There is a multiple ways you can do this:

1)
To go to the feed view use `present()` and then if you want to get back use `dismiss()`
and the put dismiss function inside of an action of a back button you create in the feed view that you may put it the left upper corner of the view for instance.

2)
You can use `NavigationController` to go to the feed view and back using the navigation back button.

for me I use the first one because it is more flexible and because I use code instead of storyboard it is easier for me.(Thats just my opinion)